# Has Hive already been completely 'solved' for AI?

Tags: computer-ai, hive

According to [some calculations](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/846447/hive-challenge-how-complex-hive), Hive has not too many positions to check them all out through programming, and basically make the best possible AI for it. Has it been done yet?

Comment: I don't know Hive, but most people in that thread are only talking about the placement of the _first three pieces_, which probably isn't enough to solve the game.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich oh, now I see. And next pieces' placements raise total number exponentially, I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, just the total number of placements is far too huge to "solve", and that doesn't even start to take into account movements occurring between placements.